# How to pass custom object as parameter in window.open javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, dfc

I'm trying to pass IDfSysObject as parameter in window.open() but I guess the IDfSysObject is getting converted to String and while retrieving, it is not letting me convert it back to IDfSysObject.

Here is my javascript code

```
function myFunction(objid, objname)
{
     
     window.open("view.jsp?uid="+objid+"&name="+objname,"","heightP0 ,widthP0");
    
    
}
```

here is how I'm trying to fetch it

```
Object obj = (Object)request.getParameter("uid");
sysObj = (IDfSysObject)obj;
```

I was hoping if there is anyway to send custom object as parameter? or if there is any way at all to pass this IDfSysObject to another jsp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IDfSysObject does not serialize like this. You have to do as follows:

To get object Id of a sysobject:

```
IDfSysObject obj = ....
String objectId = obj.getObjectId().toString();

// now pass the objectId to the JS code, it is a string
```

to fetch a sys object having its id, you need IDfSession, which you get when you connect to the repository. Once you have it, it is simple:

```
IDfSysObject obj = session.getObject(new DfId(objectId));
```